# How to update Angular model with $http response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, sails.js

I'm building an http request in Angular using `$http` and trying to update a model located in '$scope' with the data return in the response. When I receive the response from my node backend, I'm setting '$scope.data = data;' within the success callback. When I step through the javascript, I can see that the response is correct and the status code is present. 
Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
angular.module("Sample").controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {

this.testcall = function (url) {

  $http.post(url).success(function (data, status) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.status = status;
    console.log($scope.data);
  }).error(function (data, status) {
    console.log('failed');
    $scope.response = 'failed call';
    $scope.status = status;
  });
};
}
```

And in my html template I have the controller set in the div and I'm trying to display that response.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  {{data}}
</div>
```

I can set a value to data and have it appear on load, but when the value changes it's not being redrawn. It was my understanding that '$http' causes '$digest' to be called which should redrawn any modified models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe my initial problem was the `$scope`. I ended up solving the problem by creating a new directive in an attempt to isolate the scope as well as the problem.

Below is my button-directive.js and markup respectively.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('Sample', []);

  app.directive('submitButton', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {}
    };
  });

  app.controller('SubmitCtrl', ['$http', '$scope',
    function($http, $scope) {
      this.submit = function() {
        console.log('hit');
        $http.get('http://ip.jsontest.com/').success(function(data, status) {
          $scope.data = data;
          $scope.status = status;
          console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data, status) {
          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.data = data;
        });
      };
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Sample">
  <div ng-controller="SubmitCtrl as controller">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="controller.submit()">Submit</button>

    Response Data: {{data}}
    <br/>Status Code: {{status}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get it working you need to bind scope variable to controller `this` context
write `this.data = data;` instead of `$scope.data` because you are using `controllerAs` syntax.

**Code**

```
  $http.post(url).success(function (data, status) {
    console.log(data);
    this.data = data;
    this.status = status;
    console.log(this.data);
  }).error(function (data, status) {
    console.log('failed');
    this.response = 'failed call';
    this.status = status;
  });
```

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  {{main.data}}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm injecting '$scope' into the controller though. Shouldn't the markup recognize it?

Answer (score 2):

I've recreated nearly your exact scenario in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GO6EgqhThHJRcOXO9w7c?p=preview) and everything is working as expected.

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $http) {
 this.testcall = function(url) {
   $http.get(url).success(function(data, status) {
     console.log(data);
     $scope.data = data;
     $scope.status = status;
     console.log($scope.data);
   }).error(function(data, status) {
     console.log('failed');
     $scope.response = 'failed call';
     $scope.status = status;
   });
 };
}

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

angular.module('sample', [])
 .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
          ng-click="main.testcall('data.json')">Test Call</button>
  {{data}}
</div>
```

There may be a problem in the larger example you aren't showing us.

Comment: I ended up breaking out the button into a custom directive and making the http request from there.

Comment: I tried defining data with this.data = "bla" and then updating data with the http request like this.data = data..... and NO dice!!  For some reason, the main.data or this.data variable doesn't get updated.  It gets stored once and that's it?  but it works just fine with $scope... so I dunno.  Maybe it's something with the databinding on the view?  I hate angular

Comment: @rikkitikkitumbo - Perhaps if you ask a separate question, or fork the plunker above I can help you out.

Comment: here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/PoPSqXDTBWrrS6Gqur5a?p=preview  I think that link will work?  Basically, I've replaced the $scope.data with this.data and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @rikkitikkitumbo - I see what is going on, and it has nothing to do with Angular. I have forked and updated the plunker with all the information you need to understand. http://plnkr.co/edit/vLWXPJ6oJF8t8juebGw7?p=preview